# Higher order derivatives in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322833/higher-order-gradients-in-pytorch) and wrote below code. As you can see, my code stores intermediate outputs also and I want higher order derivatives(order=2,3) of `one_hot` wrt them. But I'm getting `RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior`. But I clearly construct graph using `one_hot` which should be in the graph. I want higher order derivatives of `one_hot` wrt all intermediate outputs, so is there any efficient way of calculating in least computation possible rather than calculating for each intermediate output separately(I mean using derivatives of `interme_out[3]` for calculating derivatives of `interme_out[0]`). Is there any option to not calculate cross-derivatives? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(10,20)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(20,30)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(30,40)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(40,50)
        self.interme_outs = [[],[],[],[]]

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        self.interme_outs[0] = x
        x = self.linear2(x)
        self.interme_outs[1] = x
        x = self.linear3(x)
        self.interme_outs[2] = x
        x = self.linear4(x)
        self.interme_outs[3] = x
        return x

model = Model()
inputs = torch.rand(1,10)
output = model(inputs)

index = np.argmax(output.cpu().data.numpy(), axis=-1)
one_hot = output[0][index]

for i in range(3):
    H = grad(one_hot,model.interme_outs[0],create_graph=True)[0]
    one_hot = H.sum()
```