PyTorch how to use the gradient of an intermediate variable in the computation graph of a later variable
point_2 = torch.tensor([0.2, 0.8], device=device, requires_grad=True)
p = torch.cat((point_2, torch.tensor([0], device=device)), 0)

x_verts = torch.tensor([0.0, 1.0, 0.0], device=device, requires_grad=True)
y_verts = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 1.0], device=device, requires_grad=True)
z_verts = torch.tensor([0.1, -0.1, 0.2], device=device, requires_grad=True)

v1_2d = torch.cat((torch.index_select(x_verts, 0, torch.tensor([0])), torch.index_select(y_verts, 0, torch.tensor([0])), torch.tensor([0])))
v2_2d = torch.cat((torch.index_select(x_verts, 0, torch.tensor([1])), torch.index_select(y_verts, 0, torch.tensor([1])), torch.tensor([0])))
v3_2d = torch.cat((torch.index_select(x_verts, 0, torch.tensor([2])), torch.index_select(y_verts, 0, torch.tensor([2])), torch.tensor([0])))


area_3 = torch.cross(v2_2d - v1_2d, v3_2d - v1_2d)
area = torch.index_select(area_3, 0, torch.tensor([2]))

alpha_3 = 0.5 * torch.cross(v2_2d - p, v3_2d - p) / area
beta_3 = 0.5 * torch.cross(v3_2d - p, v1_2d - p) / area
gamma_3 = 0.5 * torch.cross(v1_2d - p, v2_2d - p) / area

alpha = torch.index_select(alpha_3, 0, torch.tensor([2]))
beta = torch.index_select(beta_3, 0, torch.tensor([2]))
gamma = torch.index_select(gamma_3, 0, torch.tensor([2]))

z = alpha * torch.index_select(z_verts, 0, torch.tensor([0])) + beta * torch.index_select(z_verts, 0, torch.tensor([1])) + gamma * torch.index_select(z_verts, 0, torch.tensor([2]))

z.backward()


grad_norm = torch.norm(point_2.grad ) # <= disconnection

f = torch.tanh(10.0 * (grad_norm - 2.0))
f.backward() # <= error

print(x_verts.grad)
print(y_verts.grad)
print(z_verts.grad)


I have this code which fails because I use a variable's .grad value as input to another variable. How can I fix this?

possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322833/higher-order-gradients-in-pytorch

Not specifically looking to use a higher order gradient directly. The answers to this question does not address the graph disconnection I'm having

Can you post the actual error message you are getting and elaborate on what you are actually trying to achieve ? If you want to backprop the norm of the gradients, it is akin to computing higher order derivatives and you will need to use z.backward(create_graph=True) as highlighted in the duplicated question.
Also, you probably want to differentiate the squared norm of the gradient instead of the norm, to avoid NaN as was mentioned in another one of your questions

I am not sure what exact scenario you are using it for, or how you expect it to work but, assuming you just want to access the value of gradient as a new source node in the graph, the issue would be the value accessed by .grad is not a tensor with requires_grad true.
print(point_2.requires_grad) # True
print(point_2.grad.requires_grad) # False

So you have to clone and detach the value then make require_grad True
grad_norm = torch.norm(point_2.grad.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True))

